# Ggmap-geompoint, how to make grouping?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

Suppose I have this dataframe

```
latitude   longitude   category
42.39905   -72.93871          A
42.39905   -73.93871          B
43.37471   -73.36336          A
43.37471   -74.36336          B
44.28322   -74.31423          B
```

What I would like to do is to group the coordinates by its integer. Then for each group, I could create a bubble with a size function on the counts in a group.

The colour diverges from A to B, based on how many A than B. So far, I've been doing this,

```
map = get_map(location="jk",zoom=6,source="stamen")
#Plot the point
ggmap(map)+
  geom_point(data=zipmap,
         aes(x=round(longitude),y=round(latitude),colour=category))+
  scale_color_brewer(type='div')
```

But as you would expect, the colour is not diverging, and the size of the bubble is not implemented. How could I achieve this? I can't use `scale_x_continuous`, as it already used somewhere in `ggmap`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one direction to try.

```
dput(df)
structure(list(latitude = c(42.39905, 42.39905, 43.37471, 43.37471, 
44.28322), longitude = c(-73, -74, -73, -74, -74), category = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), latround = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("42", "43", "44"), class = "factor"), 
    longround = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("-74", 
    "-73"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("latitude", "longitude", 
"category", "latround", "longround"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

df$latround <- as.factor(round(df$latitude)) # round the coords
df$longround <- as.factor(round(df$longitude))

library(dplyr) # group by rounded coordinates and count the categories
df2 <- df %>% group_by(latround) %>% summarise(catnumber = n())

  latround catnumber
1       42         2
2       43         2
3       44         1
library(ggmap)
```

From here you don't specify the location jk so I outlined an approach to plotting.

```
map <- get_map(location="jk",zoom=6,source="stamen")
#Plot the point
ggmap(map)+
  geom_point(df2, aes(x=longround),y=latround), size = catnumber, colour=catnumber))+
  scale_color_brewer(type='div') # more is needed in the ggmap code
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used approach that's similar to you. But right now still stuck in the scale_color_brewer. The warning said **Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale**. How to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried pal = "choose your color brewer palette" as the argument to scale_color_brewer?  What map are you using; "jk" doesn't help us reproduce your problem.

Comment: I ended up using scale fill, but I can't set the color. Here's the code                  `map = get_map(location="ny",zoom=6,source="stamen")
ggmap(map,fullpage = T)+
  geom_point(data=df,
             aes(x=lonmean,y=latmean,
                 size=round((count-mean(df$count))/sd(df$count)),
                 fill=round((diff-mean(df$diff))/sd(df$diff))))+
  scale_fill_distiller(type = 'div',palette = 5,
                       guide=guide_legend(title="difference"))+
  scale_size_area(guide=guide_legend(title='Population in area'))`

Comment: Basically, 'count' columns will always return positive. Because It return the count for every group. 'diff' columns return count 'A' - count 'B' for every group. 'diff' will sometimes return negative. So that's why I want to do some diverging with respect to difference. I want both of these columns to scale to max 5 level. So maybe I want to do `rescale` instead of convert it into standardized score.